# Swift. EXC_BREAKPOINT on getting CMAudioFormatDescription

Tags: swift, avfoundation, core-media

I'm trying to retrieve sample rate and channels count from audio file.
I've got in runtime "EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT)" error on this line:

```
let audioFormstDesc = descriptions[0] as CMAudioFormatDescription
```

This is the simplest version of code I use:

```
import AVFoundation
import CoreMedia
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
        let song = query.items[0] as MPMediaItem
        let url = song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as NSURL
        let songAsset = AVURLAsset.URLAssetWithURL(url, options: nil)
        let trackAsset = songAsset.tracks[0] as AVAssetTrack
        if let descriptions = trackAsset.formatDescriptions
        {
            let audioFormstDesc = descriptions[0] as CMAudioFormatDescription
            let streamBasicDescription = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(audioFormstDesc)
        }
    }
}
```

In Objective-C this code works just right:

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
MPMediaItem *song = [[query items] objectAtIndex:0];
NSURL *url = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
AVAssetTrack *trackAsset = songAsset.tracks[0];

UInt32 sampleRate = 0, channelCount = 0;
NSArray* descriptions = trackAsset.formatDescriptions;
CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef audioFormstDesc = (__bridge CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef)descriptions[0];
const AudioStreamBasicDescription* audioStreamDesc = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(audioFormstDesc);
if(audioStreamDesc)
{
    sampleRate = audioStreamDesc->mSampleRate;
    channelCount = audioStreamDesc->mChannelsPerFrame;
}
```

`println(descriptions[0])` prints into console:

```
<CMAudioFormatDescription 0x15d3b690 [0x387e5ad0]>
```

How to deal with that error?

Comment: Looks weird to me, too. Can't see anything wrong with your code. Personally, I'd probably cast the array as a whole, rather than the individual elements, but that results in the same error (a trap in dynamicCastUnknownClass, which seems to indicate that CMAudioFormatDescription isn't a known type. Odd, as inspecting formatDescriptions tells you that it *is* an array of CMAudioFormatDescription.

Comment: Erik Aigner, for now I hardcoded sample rate, channels count and do other work. I hope problem will be fixed in next beta / GM. Otherwise I'll get back to this bug.

Comment: You'll see this if you attempt to load a MediaItem that is on iTunes Match (cloud) and not downloaded locally on the device.

Comment: @Sandoze yes, but on the same device with the same track objc code works, while swift code doesn't

Answer (score -1):

In Swift and xcode 6 beta this kind of error appears sometimes if you compile with "swift optimization level" -O (Fastest). Try to set optimization level to -Onone in "Build Settings".

Comment: I'm doing it in debug mode with -Onone, but thanks for suggestion